# MySQL optimization - Difference between WHERE on VARCHAR and on MEDIUMINT

Tags: mysql, optimization, int, varchar

I've been needing to do a lot of optimization on mysql queries and I am considering reworking queries on a user's account so that instead of performing a query "WHERE username = a varchar" I am thinking about "WHERE user_id = a number." I've been looking into this, but am wondering if it would it be worth the effort to go through all the changes to the system for this improvement?

Comment: Do you have an index on either column?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you have an index on either of the columns, because creating an index is a way of optimization. however , updating a table with indices takes more time than updating a table without and index : check simple explanation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp)